# How to validate Elasticsearch Painless scripts?

Tags: elasticsearch, compilation, kibana, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

We use many **ScriptQuery** and **ScriptField** in our project, and provide inline scripts for them in painless language.

My question is, how can we validate these painless scripts? In other words, how to make sure that they will compile?

The approach we use today is to test them out locally through Kibana. However, this is manual, error prone and not scalable. I am looking for a programmatic way or utility to validate painless scripts, so that I can plug it into the CI/CD pipeline. 
Is the compiler Elasticsearch uses under the hood open source ? Or is there some other way?

Elasticsearch version 5.4

Sample Query in Kibana with Painless script used for ScriptField and ScriptQuery

```
GET myIndex/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "LastName": {
      "script": {
        "inline": "if(doc['Author']!= null && doc['Author'].value != null){return doc['Author'].value.toUpperCase();}return null;",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "inline": "def lastName = '';if(doc['Author']!= null && doc['Author'].value != null){lastName = doc['Author'].value.toUpperCase();}if(doc.containsKey('LastName') && doc['LastName']!= null && doc['LastName'].value != null){lastName = doc['LastName'].value;}return (lastName.toLowerCase().startsWith(params.SearchParam.toLowerCase()));",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "params": {
                      "SearchParam": "d"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An integration test can start an Elasticsearch node on the local computer, and then send requests to it. The [embedded-elasticsearch](https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch) library can conveniently download a specified Elasticsearch version and start it in a separate process.

```
embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder()
    .withElasticVersion(Version.CURRENT.number())
    .withSetting(PopularProperties.CLUSTER_NAME, CLUSTER_NAME)
    .withSetting(PopularProperties.TRANSPORT_TCP_PORT, transportTcpPort)
    .withIndex(INDEX_NAME, IndexSettings.builder()
        .withSettings(getClass().getResourceAsStream("settings-mappings.json"))
        .build())
    .build()
    .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

elasticserach support dev tools to validate scripts, by using this tool you can compile scrips and if its not compiled it will show you validation error.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/devtools-kibana.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31220464)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch now exposes a [Painless execute API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.5/painless-execute-api.html) for this purpose:

> The Painless execute API runs a script and returns a result.
>
> Use this API to build and test scripts, such as when defining a script for a runtime field.

The API is in technical preview as of version 8.5. See here for the related [Opensearch API docs](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/script-apis/exec-stored-script/).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to avoid script misusing

I've made a query from the question unscripted and keep its functionality

Mapping

```
PUT /authors_last_names
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "author": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "uppercased": {
                        "analyzer": "uppercase_standard_analyzer",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "lowercased": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_lowercase_standard_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            },
            "last_name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "uppercased": {
                        "analyzer": "uppercase_standard_analyzer",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "lowercased": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "edge_ngram_lowercase_standard_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "max_ngram_diff": "6",
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercase_standard_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                },
                "edge_ngram_lowercase_standard_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "edge_ngram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "uppercase_standard_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "uppercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 5,
                    "preserve_original": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Documents

```
PUT /authors_last_names/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"author":"joe johnson", "last_name": "johnson"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"author":"jonnas massy"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"last_name": "joachim"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"author": "don dobbs"}
```

Unscripted Query

```
GET /authors_last_names/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "d",
                        "fields": [
                            "author.lowercased",
                            "last_name.lowercased"
                        ],
                        "analyzer": "lowercase_standard_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "authors_last_names",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "author" : "joe johnson",
                    "last_name" : "johnson"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "authors_last_names",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "2",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "author" : "jonnas massy"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : "authors_last_names",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "3",
                "_score" : 0.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "last_name" : "joachim"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Think like a search engine and not algorithmically

See my answer with [replacing the `scripted_metric` aggregation with the cardinality aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78225542/elasticsearch-doc-null-pointer-exception-error-for-scripted-metric-on-date-histo/78239664#78239664) as well