# Elasticsearch doc null pointer exception error for scripted metric on date_histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastisearch I have an key that is an array I need to count the unique items in the array. Without overlapping items of other documents.
So I made this:

The scripted_metric works when it isn't in the date_histogram

```php
'aggs' => [
    'groupByWeek' => [
        'date_histogram' => [
            'field' => 'date',
            'calendar_interval' => '1w',
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'count_unique_locations' => [
                'scripted_metric' => [
                     'init_script' => 'state.locations = []',
                     'map_script' => 'state.locations.addAll(doc.unique_locations_with_error)',
                     'combine_script' => 'return state.locations',
                     'reduce_script' => "
                         def locations = [];
                         for (state in states) {
                             for(location in state) {
                                 if(!locations.contains(location) && location != '' ) {
                                     locations.add(location); 
                                 }
                             }
                        }
                        return locations.length;
                    ",
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

When I run the query I get this error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause":[],
    "type":"search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason":"",
    "phase":"fetch",
    "grouped":true,
    "failed_shards":[],
    "caused_by":{
      "type":"script_exception",
      "reason":"runtime error",
      "script_stack":[
        "locations = []; ","            ^---- HERE"],
        "script":"def locations = []; for (state in states) { for(location in state){if(!locations.contains(location) && location != '' ) {locations.add(location); }}} return locations.length;",
      "lang":"painless",
      "position":{
        "offset":16,
        "start":4,
        "end":20
      },
      "caused_by":{
       "type":"null_pointer_exception",
       "reason":"cannot access method/field [iterator] from a null def reference"
      }
    }
  },
  "status":400
}
```

I think it has something to do with that doc now null is but I don't know why of how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count unique array items in documents from a date range, you can use an unscripted aggregation

Mapping

```
PUT /unique_array_item
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Documents

```
PUT /unique_array_item/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"date":"2024-03-28","text":["banana","banana"]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"date":"2024-03-28","text":["apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","apple","banana"]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"date":"2024-03-14","text":["cherry","banana","apple"]}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"date":"2024-03-14","text":["pineapple"]}
```

Query with aggregations

```
GET /unique_array_item/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "aggs": {
        "by_week": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "date",
                "calendar_interval": "1w",
                "min_doc_count": 1
            },
            "aggs": {
                "date_interval_unique_array_item_count": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_week" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key_as_string" : "2024-03-11T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key" : 1710115200000,
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "date_interval_unique_array_item_count" : {
                        "value" : 4
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string" : "2024-03-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "key" : 1711324800000,
                    "doc_count" : 2,
                    "date_interval_unique_array_item_count" : {
                        "value" : 2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Test it:

- "2024-03-11T00:00:00.000Z": `["cherry","banana","apple","pineapple"]`
  = 4
- "2024-03-25T00:00:00.000Z": `["apple","banana"]` = 2

Response is correct